# Convert html string to xml and populate datagrid using xml file

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Using htmlagilitypack i'm extracting the html content from a web page and storing it in a string. I have even removed all the tags in the output. Now i want to populate the data grid with the values inside the output string. I thought of converting this string which has html content to xml and use it as source for datagrid. When i convert html string to xml the output is looking like below code,

 CRM

```
        &amp;nbsp;
        some text

          education details

          Id details 
      Salary
      Experience
      Location
      Name 
                    Mobile: 
                    Region 
        &amp;nbsp;
        Similar Resumes    New&amp;nbsp; crm


        &amp;nbsp;
        crm

          education details

          Id details 

      Experience

      Name 

                    Telephone: Region 
        &amp;nbsp;
        Similar Resumes    &amp;nbsp; CRM


        &amp;nbsp;
```

Here there are no tags in xml file, hence don't know how make these values display in datagrid.

Comment: yes, i want this to be populated in row wise in windows application datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

See question [What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) to read more and

Remember: `&amp;nbsp;` need converted to space. Text input in CDATA is your text for output in grid.

Example

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
    some text

      education details

      Id details 
  Salary
  Experience
  Location
  Name 
                Mobile: 
                Region 
    Similar Resumes    New crm


   ...
]]> 
</description>
```